# JS | How to run functions iteratively with async await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function

```
async function go(text)
{
    var response = await say(text);
    document.write(response + '<br>')
}
```

And a promise

```
function say(text)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (enterPressed) resolve(text);
    });
}
```

I want to run the go function each time when the user pressed enter. For example, the script is:

```
go ("hello");
go ("goodbye")
```

I don't want these functions to be run immediately, I want first hello, then waiting for enter, then goodbye.
Any methods?

Comment: `await go("hello"); await go("goodbye");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
async function foo() {
    while (true) {
        await go("hello");
        await go("goodbye");
    }
}
foo();
```

Comment: I added event listener on keydown, then enterPressed = true. But nothing is happening, even I trigger it

Answer (score 0):

Did it. Thanks to Sandy Berkowitz.

```
async function go(text)
    {
        var response = await say(text);
        document.write(response + '<br>')
    }

    function say(text)
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => 
            {
                if (e.keyCode == 13)
                {
                    resolve(text);
                }
            })
        });
    }

    async function foo()
    {
        await go('go');
        await go('Hello');
        await go('How are you?')
    }

    foo();
```

Comment: But I think I should removeEventListener each promise... Should I?

Comment: Yes, you should clean up the event listener when you don't need it any more